# Switch element positions with css from above to aside when using Bootstrap 3.0 griding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 with its grid system and have on my page two divs one above the other.

I want to let the users the ability to switch the view so these `div`s will be one ***aside*** the other (on clicking a button). Can I do it using only CSS3?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
           <div class="alert alert-info">
               <!-- first div content-->
           </div>
           <div class="alert alert-info">
               <!-- second div content-->
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **input checkbox** for control state and make lable as button. Checkbox must be placed before your code.
In HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">It's button</label>
<div class="your_div">Your div</div>
```

Then you have two chunk of CSS:

```
#checkbox{ %unchecked state% }
#checkbox ~ .your_div{ %unchecked state% }
```

and

```
#checkbox:checked{ %checked state% }
#checkbox:checked ~ .your_div{ %checked state% }
```

Some time ago I test this trick http://codepen.io/KZee/pen/JdZeqv and it works perfect.

Comment: Hi KZee, I don't have a problem with activate an event (by checkbox, button etc.) but with the css manipulation.  Thanks anyway.